# jQuery show/hide animation, keep height on objects until animation is finished

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a HTML form which requires the possibility of some simple conditional fields to be toggled on/off. My problem is related to jQuery animation and object height not being preserved while the animation is in transition. This is causing a buggy jump in the animation transition.

See this fiddle to better understand the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n3frxf6m/4/

When the checkbox is ticked, it replaces the default input field #4 with a conditional field #3.

I have tried a couple of methods, including replacing `display: none` to `visibility: visible` and using `opacity` in the script, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Is there an elegant way to make show/hide animations like this smooth?

```
 <div style="width: 300px;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide" /> Check me
      </div>

      <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="text" value="Field 1" />
      </div>

      <div style="float: right;">
        <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
      </div>

      <div id="hidden" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" value="Field 3 (conditional field)" />
      </div>

      <div id="visible">
        <input type="text" value="Field 4" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" value="Field 5" />
      </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#show_hide').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#hidden").show(500);
    $("#visible").hide(500);
  } else {
    $("#hidden").hide(500);
    $("#visible").show(500);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the important code to your question. Instead of just a link to the code.

Comment: Question updated with the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two first divs have CSS float property. So you need to clear this behaviour for the next divs. I added a third div after with `clear:both`property, it gives:

https://jsfiddle.net/n3frxf6m/6/

Comment: Yes, I did it to better visualise the animation problem. If the float(s) are removed, a slight jump is still visible in the animation.

Comment: Please to look at my edit, I made a mistake regarding the first link, now it is updated

Comment: Excellent. Such a simple solution to an annoying problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help. Good day

Answer (score 1):

As you have different floating object to right and left, you have to clear floating effect by `clear:both` on 3rd and 4th objects.

```
#visible{clear:both}
#hidden{clear:both}
```

Please check the fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/n3frxf6m/3/

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! Such a simple solution to an annoying problem.